# Create bins of months from dates of a year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe containing transactions at a supermarket, **each row represents a transaction done on a certain date**, I want to find the average  number of transactions done per month and also have to plot a graph of the same, the date column looks like this

```
        DATE 
        2018-10-17  
        2019-05-14 
        2019-05-20  
        2018-08-17  
        2018-08-18  
        2019-05-19  
        2019-05-16
```

I want to plot a graph containing months on x-axis and average transactions on y-axis
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that *DATE* is an index in your dataframe
2. I've assumed you have a transaction count,  I've called this *transaction*
3. then just `resample()` and `plot()`

```
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2019,5,1), dt.datetime(2020,10,17)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":d, "transactions":[random.randint(1,5) for i in d]}).set_index("DATE")
df.resample("M").agg({"transactions":"mean"}).plot()
```

[image]